# how to toggle addClass and removeClass?

Tags: javascript, jquery

my code:

```
<a href=# onclick="obj.addClass('fliph'); return false;">toggle</a>
```

i want click **toggle** to `obj.addClass('fliph')`,then click again run `obj.removeClass('fliph')`.

how to fix my code?

thanks all! :)

Comment: jQuery has toggleClass method just exactly for this reason

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
<a href=# onclick="obj.toggleClass('fliph'); return false;">toggle</a>
```

Answer (score 10):

Do it unobtrusive, whereever possible.

```
<a href=# class="fliph">toggle</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.fliph').click(function(){
       $(this).toggleClass('fliph');
   });
});
```